# Add comma with Variable name as suffix

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, suffix

I am working on a scenario to append all scores of a correlation matrix one below the other by combining two variables in one column and scores in another column and finally sort them in descending to find out the variables with maximum scores.

I am almost there but finding it hard to append comma (,) in a for loop along with variable name as suffix (i.e. line 6in the below code **series.add_suffix(', Temp9am')** where var is the variable name from for loop and I need , in front of it.

Please find the below code and I have attached screenshots of the dataframe I am working with.

```
df_sorted_
corre_score = pd.DataFrame()
for var in df_sorted_.columns:
    series = df_sorted_[var]
    series_ = series.add_suffix(', var')
    series1 = pd.DataFrame(series_)
    series1.columns = ['Score_']
    series1
```

Dataframe Image is [image]

Expected Output is as follows with all variables appended one below the other [image]

Comment: Do you not need to use `var` as var and not as string? I am not quite sure if that's your problem, but it's something I spotted. `series.add_suffix(',' + var)` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

using `stack` to stack values in one column.

then, rename the index.

```py
dfn = df.stack()
dfn.index = pd.Series(list(dfn.index)).str.join(', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `stack` and `<dataframe>.index.map(','.join)`

```
rs = np.random.RandomState(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(rs.rand(5, 5), columns= [ chr(i+66) for i in range(5)])
corr = df.corr()
```

---

**corr:**

```
    B           C           D           E           F
B   1.000000    0.861882    -0.687578   0.220408    -0.965567
C   0.861882    1.000000    -0.770134   -0.283359   -0.807373
D   -0.687578   -0.770134   1.000000    0.341363    0.701713
E   0.220408    -0.283359   0.341363    1.000000    -0.262302
F   -0.965567   -0.807373   0.701713    -0.262302   1.000000
```

---

```
corr[corr==1]=np.nan

s = corr.stack()
s.index = s.index.map(','.join)
pd.DataFrame(s, columns=['Score'])
```

---

```
    Score
B,C 0.861882
B,D -0.687578
B,E 0.220408
B,F -0.965567
C,B 0.861882
C,D -0.770134
C,E -0.283359
C,F -0.807373
D,B -0.687578
D,C -0.770134
D,E 0.341363
D,F 0.701713
E,B 0.220408
E,C -0.283359
E,D 0.341363
E,F -0.262302
F,B -0.965567
F,C -0.807373
F,D 0.701713
F,E -0.262302
```

Comment: `corr[corr==1]=np.nan` <-- use this if you don't want include same variable pair.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right,you can do it like this.

```
df.index=df.index+","
pd.DataFrame(df.stack(),columns=["Score_"]).sort_values(by='Score_', ascending=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt), this solves the issue of NaN omissions in `df.stack`:

```
>>> df = pd.get_dummies(list('abcd'))

>>> df
   a  b  c  d
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0
2  0  0  1  0
3  0  0  0  1

>>> df = df.melt(value_name='Score', ignore_index=False)

>>> df.index = df.index.astype(str) + ', ' + df.pop('variable')

      Score
0, a      1
1, a      0
2, a      0
3, a      0
0, b      0
1, b      1
2, b      0
3, b      0
0, c      0
1, c      0
2, c      1
3, c      0
0, d      0
1, d      0
2, d      0
3, d      1
```

In your case you won't need to convert `df.index` to `astype(str)`.